# Stability of the Trapezoidal method for solving IVPs (Proof verification)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

In Kendall Atkinson's *An Introduction to Numerical Analysis*, the author proves that the explicit Euler method for solving an inhomogeneous IVP is stable with respect to perturbations to the vector field and the initial iterate. As an exercise, I have tried to formulate and prove an analogous result for the implicit Trapezoidal method. I'm just looking to make sure my theorem statement and proof are correct.

> **Theorem**. *Let $[x_0,b]$ be a finite interval, let $h > 0$, let $N \equiv N(h) := \lfloor \frac{b-x_0}{h} \rfloor$, and let $f: [x_0,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly Lipschitz in its second argument with constant $K \geq 0$ (that is, $|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| \leq K|y_1 - y_2|$ for all $x \in [x_0,b]$ and all $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$), and assume that $hK \leq 1$. Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ be a chosen initial iterate and let  $y_n \equiv y_h(x_n), \; 1 \leq n \leq N$ be the iterates obtained for solving the IVP $Y'(x) = f(x,Y(x)), \, Y(x_0) = Y_0$ by the (implicit) Trapezoidal method, given by*
> \begin{equation}
>    \hspace{1.2cm} y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{2}\left[f(x_n,y_n) + f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \right], \qquad n \geq 0 \hspace{1.2cm} (1)
> \end{equation}
>
> *Let $\delta:[x_0,b]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function (denoting a structural perturbation to the vector field $f$) and let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ be some initial perturbation. Define a sequence of perturbed iterates $(z_n)_{n \geq 0}$ by setting $z_0 := y_0 + \epsilon$ defining $z_n$ for $n \geq 1$ according to the recursive equation*
> \begin{equation}
>    \hspace{1cm} z_{n+1} = z_n + \frac{h}{2}\left[f(x_n,z_n) + f(x_{n+1},z_{n+1}) + \delta(x_n) \right]. \hspace{1cm} (2)
> \end{equation}
>
> *Then there exists constants $C_1,C_2$ independent of $h$ such that*
> \begin{align*}
>     \hspace{1.8cm} \max_{0 \leq n \leq N(h)} |z_n - y_n| \leq C_1 |\epsilon| + C_2 \| \delta \|_u. \hspace{1.8cm} (3)
> \end{align*}

(Here, $\|\delta\|_u := \sup\{|\delta(s_1,s_2)|: (s_1,s_2) \in [x_0,b]^2 \}.)$ Below is my proof attempt.

*Proof*: Let $d_n := |z_n - y_n|$ for all $n \geq 0$. Subtracting (1) from (2) gives
\begin{align*}
    d_{n+1} = d_n + \frac{h}{2} \left[ f(x_n,z_n) - f(x_n,y_n) \right] + \frac{h}{2} \left[f(x_{n+1},z_{n+1}) - f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \right] + \frac{h}{2} \delta(x_{n-1},x_n). 
\end{align*}

Then applying the Triangle Inequality and the Lipschitz condition on $f$ gives
\begin{align*}
    d_{n+1} &\leq d_n + \frac{h}{2}K|z_n - y_n| + \frac{h}{2}K|z_{n+1}-y_{n+1}| + \frac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u \\[3pt]
    &= (1 + \tfrac{hK}{2})d_n + \tfrac{hK}{2}d_{n+1} + \tfrac{h}{2}\|\delta\|_u,
\end{align*}

which then implies
\begin{align*}
    d_{n+1} \leq \left(\frac{1 + \frac{hK}{2}}{1-\frac{hK}{2}}\right) d_n + \frac{h}{2}\|\delta\|_u.
\end{align*}
(The sign on the inequality does not flip because $hK \leq 1$). Now using the fact that $\frac{1+x}{1-x} \leq 1 + 4x$ for $0 \leq x < 1/2$, we obtain the bound
\begin{align*}
    d_{n+1} \leq (1 + 2hK)d_n + \frac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u. 
\end{align*}

Now observe that
\begin{align*}
     d_1 &\leq (1 + 2hK) |\epsilon| + \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u \\[3pt]
     d_2 &\leq (1 + 2hK) \left[ (1 + 2hK) |\epsilon| + \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u \right] + \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u  \\[3pt]
     &= (1 + 2hK)^2 |\epsilon| + \left[1 + (1 + 2hK) \right] \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u  \\[3pt]
     a_3 &\leq (1 + 2hK) \left[(1 + 2hK)^2 |\epsilon| + \left[1 + (1 + 2hK) \right] \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u \right] + \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u  \\[3pt]
     &= (1 + 2hK)^3 |\epsilon| + \left[1 + (1 + 2hK) + (1 + 2hK)^2 \right] \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u  \\[5pt]
     &\; \, \vdots \\
     a_n &\leq (1 + 2hK)^n |\epsilon| + \left[(1 + (1 + 2hK) + \cdots + (1 + 2hK)^{n-1} \right] \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u  \\[5pt]
     &= (1 + 2hK)^n |\epsilon| + \left[\frac{(1 + 2hK)^n - 1}{(1+2hK)-1} \right] \tfrac{h}{2} \|\delta\|_u \\[5pt]
    &= (1 + 2hK)^n |\epsilon| + \left[\frac{(1 + 2hK)^n - 1}{4K} \right] \|\delta\|_u.  
 \end{align*}
where the second to last equality is by the formula for a finite geometric series. Now using the facts that $d_n \leq a_n$ and $(1 + x)^n \leq e^{nx}$ for all integers $n \geq 0$ and all $x \geq -1$, we have
\begin{align*}
    (1 + 2hK)^n \leq e^{2Knh} = e^{2K(x_n-x_0)} \leq e^{2K(b-x_0)}. 
\end{align*}

Thus,
\begin{align*}
     d_n \leq e^{2K(b-x_0)} |\epsilon| + \frac{e^{2K(b-x_0)} - 1}{4K} \|\delta\|_u.
 \end{align*}

And since the RHS of the above inequality is independent of $n$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
    \max_{0 \leq n \leq N(h)} d_n \leq C_1 |\epsilon| + C_2 \|\delta\|_u
 \end{align*}

where $C_1 := e^{2K(b-x_0)}$ and $C_2 := \frac{e^{2K(b-x_0)} - 1}{4K}. \qquad \square$

Does the proof look okay?

Also, this is probably not as important but: when adding a vector field perturbation term $\delta$ to an implicit method of the form $y_{n+1} = G(y_{n-p},\ldots,y_{n+1})$, are the arguments of $\delta$ generally chosen to be $x_{n-p},\ldots,x_n$? Or do we also include $x_{n+1}$? (Of course, if we always assume that $\delta$ is bounded then this doesn't affect the proof, but I'm just curious.)